# Errors not displaying on View. Laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my Laravel app I did some Validation of a form in a  controller using the request variable. The validation seems to work, however when I try to display the errors in the view they are not showing up. I know the validation is working because as soon as I type something that is not a integer it brings me back to the view with the form. Here is the view with the form: (The 'if' statement that displays errorr is not working):

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
  <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
<form method='POST' action='/lorem/show'>



<label>Enter Number of Paragraphs</label>
<input type='hidden' name='_token' value='{{ csrf_token() }}'>
<input type='text'
        id='paragraph'
        name='paragraph'
        maxlength="2"
        size="5"
        <br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="header" value="header"/>Include Headers<br/><br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
&nbsp;Create </button>
</form>
```

And here is the function in my controller:

```
public function postShow (Request $request) {

  $this->validate ($request, [
  'paragraph' => 'required|integer',
 ]);
}
```

Why are the errors not showing up in the view?

Comment: Is your route inside the route group with middleware named 'web' ?
If not, that can be the problem

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Update the `postShow` to be:

```
$this->validate( $request->all(), [
   'paragraph' => 'required|integer',
]);
```

i.e. you've missing the `$request->all()`.

Change the `if` statement to:

```
@if( $errors->first() )
  <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```

If that doesn't work, verify that you are actually getting error messages back to the view by adding the following somewhere in your view:

```
{{ dd( $errors ) }}
```

Comment: I tried changing the `if` but it didn't work. When I added `{{ dd( $errors ) }}` the following showed up:

`ViewErrorBag {#167 ▼
  #bags: []
}`
It is not working still

Comment: That means you validations isn't actually throwing any errors, which is why you don't see the message showing up.

Comment: Do u have found any solution for that i am receiving same error?